# Resizing an image from within the Rails image tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to resize an image from within a Rails image tag, but its not working.

Here's my code:

```
<%= image_tag("tarmo.jpg"), :width => "50%"  %>
```

This is the error message I get:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' ...ppend=( image_tag("tarmo.jpg"), :width => "50%" );@output_b... ... ^
```

How do I fix it?

Note: I don't want to create a CSS class, I want to do it from within the rails image tag.

Comment: Show the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you have a syntax error. There is a parenthesis where it shouldn't be. So this would be correct:

```
<%= image_tag("tarmo.jpg", width: "50%") %>
```